# ERC20 how to transfer from contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

After deploying `ERC20` contract (`MyToken`), I transferred all tokens to `MyToken` contract.

Then I deployed a service contract that has one method called `claimWining()` which is supposed to transfer tokens to a caller account from `MyToken` contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract MyToken is Context, ERC20, ERC20Detailed {

    constructor () public ERC20Detailed("DEST", "DST", 18) {
        _mint(_msgSender(), 1000000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals())));
    }
}

contract Claim {

    MyToken public token;
    address myToken;

    constructor(address _tokenAddress) public {
        token = MyToken(_tokenAddress);
        myToken= _tokenAddress;
    }

    function claimWinning() public {
        // doesn't work
        token.transferFrom(myToken, msg.sender, 100000); 
    }
}
```

Here I used `transferFrom()`, but it was not working because I was unable to execute `approve()` initially.

```
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
    _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
    return true;
}
```

I found that `MyToken` contract itself should call `approve()` as `msg.sender`, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Basically, what I want is platform user calls `claimWinning()` to get rewarded with `ERC20` token. 
How can users receive tokens from `MyToken` contract?

Comment: Your conceptual problem is in "transfer tokens to ... from `MyToken` contract". This contract doesn't have any tokens by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your conceptual problem is in this requirement:**

> transfer tokens to ... from `MyToken` contract

This contract, despite being the "token manufacturer", does not own any tokens by itself.

Think of it as a bank which serves customers - each customer has an account which holds money, while the bank itself manages all of these accounts without actually owning any of them (or the money that they hold).

When this bank is created, it mints an initial supply:

```
_mint(_msgSender(), 1000000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals())));
```

But as you can see, this initial supply is minted for the bank creator.

In order to mint it for the bank itself, you would need to change it to:

```
_mint(this, 1000000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals())));
```

But since it is not the case, you need to change your requirement to:

> transfer tokens to ... from **the creator of** `MyToken` contract

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. But what happens 1,000 users need to be rewarded per day? then the creator of `MyToken` contract would call `transfer()` from `MyToken` contract 1,000 times? Is there any way that the users can pay gas fee themselves and receive tokens?

Comment: @bbusdriver: Yes. You're looking for an automated airdrop. There is at least one scheme for that which I know of, called *merkle-airdrop*.

Comment: Could you give me more information on that please?

Comment: @bbusdriver: I just did. Please see my updated comment.

Comment: Thanks. From another answer than your own, what if I send all tokens to `Claim` contract as a creator of `MyToken` and fix `claimWinning()` like `token.transfer(msg.sender, 100000);`? This way I don't need to use automated airdrop and still keep the token ecosystem?

Comment: @bbusdriver: Yes, I guess you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

If the token contract doesn't support functionality to either transfer the tokens or approve transfers then it simply can't transfer tokens. If it owns some tokens they are basically lost / burned.

Typically a token contract only holds a ledger and it's kept as simple as possible. Usually the contract itself doesn't own any tokens directly but there's another contract which handles the tokens - for example a crowdsale contract which initially owns all the tokens and distributes them around when people pay Ether for them. Or then the token contract has a `mint` functionality which mints tokens when needed, but the contract itself still doesn't ever own its own tokens.